# Using LogDNA in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, log-analysis, logdna

I was reading this page on using LogDNA in IBM Cloud

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA?topic=LogDNA-about#about

It mentions that "Log data is sent to a third party". What exactly does it mean by sent to third party? Does it mean that we need to make sure that we cannot log any personally identifiable data or any other kind of data that might not be suitable to sent to a third party? I am just trying to understand if there are any best practices on what can be logged/what cannot be logged in this case.

Comment: we have the same questions about gdpr and data locations. did you get any useful information about this topic? regards Leo

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's just informing you that LogDNA is a third party company, https://logdna.com/. Therefore the logs are being sent to a "third party" as in LogDNA.

I would defer to your companies security and compliance policies regarding suitability of the service for PII. They do have a bevy of compliances.

They are integrated with IBM Cloud and act as a common Logging service that IBM Cloud products automatically send to logs to like IBM Kubernetes Service or IBM Cloud Databases.